# "Loose" Bin Packing Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

Can't quite think of what to call this, and so my Googling is also coming up short...

I'm doing something sort of akin to the basic [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) but with a few alterations that are tripping me up.

1. The number of bins is always 3, and all 3 are always identical sizes (equal to 1/3 of the sum of all item sizes)
2. Every item must be placed in a bin
3. Items can be "fragmented" into multiple consecutive bins, if they don't fit completely in a bin. **Minimize this**.

With these three criteria (especially 3), I'm not sure the problem is even NP-hard anymore, but a 4th criteria makes this what I call a "loose" problem.

4. Bin sizes don't have to be strictly enforced.  If an item is to be "overstuffed" into a bin by, say, 10% of the bin size, that's fine, but only if it then accommodates the whole item (don't overstuff for fragmented items).

Is this still a structured problem, or did I muck up my criteria enough that it's hardly even solvable anymore?

If you're curious, I'm using this to render 3 columns (the *bins*) of many (or few) categories (the *items*) containing many (or few) links.

Target language is PHP, but pseudocode is preferable for now.

Comment: The reason the bin problem is hard is because it's minimizing the number of bins.  Since you don't seem to really be "minimizing" anything really, I doubt this is NP-hard.  Is there a guarantee that the times _can_ always fit in the bins?  If so, is there a guarantee it can be done without overstuffing?

Comment: Realistically, I suspect you can probably just use a greedy algorithm to handle 99% of the cases.

Comment: @MooingDuck yes, the bin sizes are set at 1/3 of the sum of the item sizes, so all the items should fit perfectly, but overstuffing can be done on some bins to minimize fragmentation.

Comment: How literally do you want to take the requirement to "minimize this"? If it means "fragment, but only if _absolutely necessary_," then you have to work a full non-fragmented computation in order to prove there is no non-fragmented solution. If it means "make a reasonable effort to avoid fragmentation" then you can define "reasonable effort" so that the problem is not even theoretically NP-hard. But if the problem is small enough so that it makes sense to format the output in three columns, it may not matter whether it's NP-hard.

Comment: Unless there are constraints on how you can fragment, it seems this is trivially solvable. Are there any constraints on fragmentation?

Comment: @hatchet ideally, a fragment would occur reasonably far (some percentage of the item's size) from its beginning or end.  This is to avoid a column that has a tiny piece broken off into another column. I realize that adds a whole new degree of difficulty though, so I was holding off on that.

Comment: Don't hold it back, because it matters tremendously. Otherwise, a solution could be to just put 1/3 of each thing in each of the three bins.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is simply put the largest item in the most empty bin.  If the last item would be more than the overstuff value, partition it to fit.  O(1n)  (Note that since nothing except the last would be partitioned, the bins can be rearranged so to minimize partitioning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I'd answer my own question for the sake of future visitors...

```
Loop through items largest to smallest
Does it fit wholly (overstuffing ok) in the first open bin? ...Yes
    Place it
...No
    Does it fit wholly (overstuffing ok) in the next bin? ...Yes
        Place it
    ...No
        Does it fit wholly (overstuffing ok) in the last bin? ...Yes
            Place it
        ...No
            //Place in first open bin, expecting a fragmentation
            Place x "units" of item until bin size reached (no overstuffing)
            Place y "units" of item until bin size reached (no overstuffing), starting at index x into item
            If x+y is still less than item size, place rest in last bin.
```

If incrementing the bin caused an index out of bounds, it just treats it as a "no".  Probably not the neatest implementation, but it's been treating me well so far.  Obviously, this approach is fixed for 3 bins, but I imagine it could be reasonably expanded to more (finite) bins.